# How do I accurately represent SHAP values of columns made with a hashingVectorizer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, shap

I used a `HashingVectorizer()` from sklearn to represent the unique IDs of a dataset which hashes the data into n columns, and I want to calculate the total SHAP value of this data. Is the correct way to simply add all their mean SHAP values together, or do I take the average of the values

Comment: If I am not wrong you are using SHAP value for Model interpreter. Because HashingVectorizer does not store the resulting vocabulary for that you have to use CountVectorizer. You can understand difference of both vectorizer using this link. https://kavita-ganesan.com/hashingvectorizer-vs-countvectorizer/

Comment: @VijayMaurya the issue with using a CountVectorizer is that the values I'm encoding is like credit card numbers which means that in a single dataset there will be a lot of these. They do repeat for transactions made by the same card which means that it is a pattern the machine will have to learn, but if I use a CountVectorizer it could potentially have scaling issues. Is my concern valid, and also how does using a CountVectorizer solve the problem?

Comment: I can't tell exact problem or solution without seeing sample data. But from above comment I understand you are using credit card number as feature for count number of transaction. Instead of that create new feature using different function and join this feature into your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you will get without significant additional work is [`shap.explainers.Partition`](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/shap.explainers.Partition.html), which will either accept or compute a hierarchical clustering of features.

Alternatively, it would be more principled to define your own masker - you should be able to provide a list of them for each input as described [here](https://shap-lrjball.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/shap.KernelExplainer.html).